# How to tell whether my device has gone in to suspend

Tags: linux, laptop, battery, power

I've recently been given a new work laptop and have installed Fedora 22 on it, when I have suspended it recently it has woken up and I'm pretty sure the battery has drained massively while it should be using minimal battery.

I was hoping to do this without using another device (I did consider I could ssh on to my laptop - if I open up ports to do so etc) but when I have searched for ways to monitor whether my device has been suspended all the information I find is geared towards disabling the suspend feature or fixing lid close actions.

Does anyone have a suggestion for a good way to monitor whether a device has indeed been suspended for a given period? I suspect, but am uncertain that it may have initially suspended, then woken up for some reason then drained the battery, so having times when it enters each state getting logged to a file would be excellent!

Answer (score 1):

Suspending and waking up is written to the system logs. You can check what has been logged using the [`journalctl`](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemctl.html) command, for example `journalctl -b` will show the all log entries since the last system boot.

Note (edited): This command needs to be ran as root (or `sudo` has to be prepended). (thanks meuh for pointing that out)

Comment: Thanks for the response but that doesn't work (systemctl: invalid option -- 'b')